# Como incluir banner no meio do texto?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou reconstruindo um projeto antigo, escrito em PHP com MySQL. Para fins práticos, considere como um portal de notícias.

No banco de dados existem artigos diversos, que listo no site por query simples, que gera as strings $titulo $subtitulo e $conteudo.

Preciso colocar um banner de publicidade no meio do texto $conteudo. Pensei em quebrar $conteudo em linhas para então colocar o bloco de código da publicidade, mas preferencialmente após o primeiro ou segundo paragrafo.

Portanto, qual a maneira mais recomendável pra fazer isso, na prática? Quebrar uma string em linhas e identificar os parágrafos (preg_split() ?), injetar o que eu preciso após o segundo e imprimir o restante?

**Atualizando**

Obs.: Os parágrafos do $conteudo são separados por `<br><br>`, gravados no banco de dados.

Cheguei ao código abaixo, baseado no comentário do Dvdsamm, mas não funciona corretamente, mostrando apenas o texto sem incluir `<div>BANNER</div>` após o segundo paragrafo conforme esperado.

```
$conteudo = ''.$x['conteudo'].'';

// adiciona banner
function addBanner($i)
{
static $conta = 0;
$retorno = $i[0];
if(++$conta == 2){
    $retorno .= "<div>BANNER</div>";
}
return $retorno;
}

$txt = preg_replace_callback('#(<br><br>)#', 'addBanner', $conteudo);
// adiciona banner

echo"$txt";
```

Comment: Você está utilizando algum editor WYSIWYG ou `textarea` cru?

Comment: PHP puro, sem Framework. Foi essa a pergunta?

Comment: Seus parágrafos são sempre dentro de <p></p>?

Comment: Sim, dentro de <p></p>

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse [Ideone](https://ideone.com/NqfhP9). A função, usando `preg_replace_callback()`, coloca um conteúdo (no caso, uma DIV) entre o segundo e terceiro parágrafo. Mas só funciona 1 vez por causa da variável `static`. Como não sou mt aprofundado em PHP, eu não sei como resolver isso. Mas já pode ser uma idéia.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, Dvdsamm. Ocorre que meus parágrafos estão todos (juntos) dentro de (um mesmo) <p></p>. Logo a sua proposta não resolve. Mas eu acredito que possa ser um ponto de partida bem interessante por conta do seguinte: os parágrafos são separados por <br><br> gravados no banco de dados, daí eu pensei em adaptar, conforme código que incluí na pergunta.

Comment: Como faço para utilizar este código e ao invés de inserir apenas um banner, eu consiga incluir dois banners. Em parágrafos diferentes.